# RSA signed message in java failed verifying

Tags: java, go, cryptography, rsa

I have signed a message with RSA private key in Java. It can be successfully verified in Java itself with the public key. But when I try to verify a message in Go with the same signature it failed.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. generate a signature with the sign method in java code
2. run verify method in java code
3. run the Go test function after replacing the signature string which was generated by Java

Anyway, if I use plaintext instead of hash I could successfully verify in both Java and Go (I have commented out this line of code in Java methods)

Java code

```
public static String sign(String plaintext, PrivateKey privateKey){
        try {
            Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
            byte[] hash = sha256Hash(plaintext.getBytes());
            privateSignature.update(hash);
            //privateSignature.update(plaintext.getBytes());
            byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex.toString());
            return "";
        }
}
public static void verify(String plaintext, String signature, PublicKey publicKey){
        try {
            Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
            byte[] hash = sha256Hash(plaintext.getBytes());
            publicSignature.update(hash);
            //publicSignature.update(plaintext.getBytes());
            byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

            System.out.println("Verified:"+publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes));
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex);
        }
}
public static byte[] sha256Hash(byte[] content) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return digest.digest(content);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
}
```

Go test function

```
func Test_sigVerify(t *testing.T) {
    data := []byte("Hello World")
    dig := sha256.Sum256(data)
    signature := "VP8J3fGZXgHPM9wpKpW0t3mihPSM0VFFjcrZ9IjFpazQMqbKGMryz7Z7D0ufG/hOXPZrKdgtoXQ3jXmcQyvhFB+CEo5j3KsoQ5xq5pGZoaOWjjO7tRxZ2zNfwDkCY+TOKm1JB4So1/ELQU2FCowDfJDxlezPCrAgQFAD0ZkN6Omx/0Hd2HIWCRnOgYyjJvO6DPyaUvd2N+UB0JhrLxDQSi6NJS6b2VZGHANQB3Ik7FDXO5o19qmAxgrv5/ZS1wLRqn+jClFTzbXt3DBPOFHk/3P71ugU6cCkx+BRmGJyrbSgmWi/Z4zDpwy+IdWbfJCCByoaFizZp72rxrPtYqU1fA=="

    publicKey, err := parsePublicKey3()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Public key paring error:", err)
    }

    b64, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(signature)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Decoding error:", err)
    }

    verifyErr := rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(publicKey, crypto.SHA256, dig[:], b64)
    if verifyErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Verify Error:", verifyErr)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("successfully verified")
}

func parsePublicKey3() (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    pString := `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlnOCGYMjRR1toSvSgWq2DB1ytz5VF5I1M7wkOksxnJhbgiEC7MnlrctEgPqQXWzzULk/StQSbwip39ZbDEr+uLC/yks2z1+8DmgZe8WR5b/6SBXV3hrPc/rWS0v+fYHkdJ2buhqhqcOfwYntu1tEk3tGyjubQDa6XobDZRHhuRF9mzw7Eld2Atf//wxiGzHylNVa+/SysozVy68ZUcn3tveYClxOEuVYIv3EEnsWnkBPu5/PHBplLr7t6IdJ86viB9hkdocYWj5TQgMccwees6fZ7MKcLeh+WryyajqFJsppvT70t4RmiABjrp1BWB4VEoA9PYwiOKEPsDD8OZOCSQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

    var err error
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pString))
    if block == nil {
        fmt.Println("block is nil")
        return nil, err
    }

    publicKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return publicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey), nil
}
```

Comment: If it works with `privateSignature.update(plaintext.getBytes())` then I guess Java calls the hash function automatically (you can test this by signing a message much larger than the key size). And if you have working code, what's the question, exactly?

Comment: @Peter thanks for response, if I use plain text(plaintext.getBytes()) to generate signature I can successfully verify in both Java and Go. But when I use hash, It can't be verified in Go but can be verified in Java successfully

Comment: Exactly as @Peter said, the "(hash)withRSA" Signature schemes in Java already perform the specified hash themselves, so when you add another hash operation of your own, you are doing a signature which uses (both for generate and verify, so those two match) the hash of the hash of the data instead of the hash of the data as is correct and as is done in your go code.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ok thanks for response, actually I'm getting this java signature from outside. So I don't have control on it. What can I do to successfully verify this on Go code

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  thanks. I understand the problem as both of you said java code use hashing twice.

Comment: Then you need to hash twice in Go too.